# Pass extra data to finder auth

Tags: authentication, orm, cakephp-3.0

My finder from `Auth` has conditions that I need to access `$this->request` but I don't have access for that on `UsersTable`.

**AppController::initialize**

```
$this->loadComponent('Auth', [
        'authenticate' => [
            'Form' => [
                'finder' => 'auth',
            ]
        ]
    ]);
```

**UsersTable**

```
public function findAuth(Query $query, array $options)
{
    $query
        ->select([
            'Users.id',
            'Users.name',
            'Users.username',
            'Users.password',
        ])
        ->where(['Users.is_active' => true]); // If I had access to extra data passed I would use here.

    return $query;
}
```

I need pass extra data from `AppController` to `finder` `auth` since I don't have access to `$this->request->data` on `UsersTable`.

**Update**

People are saying on comments that is a bad design so I will explain exactly what I need.

I have a table `users` but each user belongs to a `gym`.
The `username(email)` is unique only to a particular `gym` so I can have a `example@domain.com`from `gym_id 1` and another `example@domain.com` from `gym_id 2`.
On login page I have the `gym_slug` to tell to `auth finder` which `gym` the user `username` that I provided belongs.

Comment: This sounds like possibly bad design to me, could you show what you wanted to pass on? It must be possible as a behaviour in some way though :-)

Comment: I'm passing a gym slug at url so I need to get the ID of the gym based on that slug to filter at user find because I have `gym_id` at `users` table. I can access the slug by `this->request->params['gym_slug]` but I dont have accesa to this at `UsersTable`

Comment: We need a bit more information to go on here. It sounds from both the question and the comments that maybe you're authenticating a user then trying to redirect them to their gym's page? Edit your question and provide exactly what you're doing and why. You don't mention the gym until the comment above and I'm curious why you'd need the request data to redirect (if that's even what you're doing) since you have the gym_id stored in the same table.

Comment: I never mentioned `redirect` I just need the `gym_slug` on `finder` to use on `where` as a `condition`, simple as that. I will edit and explain a little more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my knowledge, there is no way to do this by passing it into the configuration in 3.1. This might be a good idea submit on the cakephp git hub as a feature request.

There are ways to do it by creating a new authentication object that extends base authenticate and then override _findUser and _query. Something like this:

```
class GymFormAuthenticate extends BaseAuthenticate
{

 /**
  * Checks the fields to ensure they are supplied.
  *
  * @param \Cake\Network\Request $request The request that contains login information.
  * @param array $fields The fields to be checked.
  * @return bool False if the fields have not been supplied. True if they exist.
  */
 protected function _checkFields(Request $request, array $fields)
 {
     foreach ([$fields['username'], $fields['password'], $fields['gym']] as $field) {
         $value = $request->data($field);
         if (empty($value) || !is_string($value)) {
             return false;
         }
     }
     return true;
 }

 /**
  * Authenticates the identity contained in a request. Will use the `config.userModel`, and `config.fields`
  * to find POST data that is used to find a matching record in the `config.userModel`. Will return false if
  * there is no post data, either username or password is missing, or if the scope conditions have not been met.
  *
  * @param \Cake\Network\Request $request The request that contains login information.
  * @param \Cake\Network\Response $response Unused response object.
  * @return mixed False on login failure.  An array of User data on success.
  */
 public function authenticate(Request $request, Response $response)
 {
     $fields = $this->_config['fields'];
     if (!$this->_checkFields($request, $fields)) {
         return false;
     }
     return $this->_findUser(
         $request->data[$fields['username']],
         $request->data[$fields['password']],
         $request->data[$fields['gym']],
     );
 }

/**
  * Find a user record using the username,password,gym provided.
  *
  * Input passwords will be hashed even when a user doesn't exist. This
  * helps mitigate timing attacks that are attempting to find valid usernames.
  *
  * @param string $username The username/identifier.
  * @param string|null $password The password, if not provided password checking is skipped
  *   and result of find is returned.
  * @return bool|array Either false on failure, or an array of user data.
  */
 protected function _findUser($username, $password = null, $gym = null)
 {
     $result = $this->_query($username, $gym)->first();

     if (empty($result)) {
         return false;
     }

     if ($password !== null) {
         $hasher = $this->passwordHasher();
         $hashedPassword = $result->get($this->_config['fields']['password']);
         if (!$hasher->check($password, $hashedPassword)) {
             return false;
         }

         $this->_needsPasswordRehash = $hasher->needsRehash($hashedPassword);
         $result->unsetProperty($this->_config['fields']['password']);
     }

     return $result->toArray();
 }

/**
  * Get query object for fetching user from database.
  *
  * @param string $username The username/identifier.
  * @return \Cake\ORM\Query
  */
 protected function _query($username, $gym)
 {
     $config = $this->_config;
     $table = TableRegistryget($config['userModel']);

     $options = [
         'conditions' => [$table->aliasField($config['fields']['username']) => $username, 'gym' => $gym]
     ];

     if (!empty($config['scope'])) {
         $options['conditions'] = array_merge($options['conditions'], $config['scope']);
     }
     if (!empty($config['contain'])) {
         $options['contain'] = $config['contain'];
     }

     $query = $table->find($config['finder'], $options);

     return $query;
 }
 }
```

For more information see this: [Creating Custom Authentication Objects](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#creating-custom-authentication-objects)

Comment: Worked to me, its a shame I could not give you the bounty before it expires

Comment: It is quite alright! Anything to help a fellow developer!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but I thought I would post the finder I am using in one of our SaaS apps built on Cakephp 3.  Does it follow DRY etc probably not. To say everything can be done X or Y way ..... you always have to bend the rules.  In this case depending on the URL (xdomain.com or ydomain.com) our app figures out who the customer is and changes layouts etc.  Also the user based is tied to Email & site_id much like yours

```
public function findAuth(\Cake\ORM\Query $query, array $options) {
    $query
            ->select([
                'Users.id',
                'Users.email',
                'Users.password',
                'Users.site_id',
                'Users.firstname',
                'Users.lastname'])
            ->where([
                'Users.active' => 1,
                'Users.site_id'=> \Cake\Core\Configure::read('site_id')
            ]);

    return $query;
}
```

Anyway hope it helps someone