# Cakephp Custom Finder for Auth, with related model

Tags: php, authentication, cakephp

First, this question builds on the question and answer here:  [Modifying AuthComponent identify method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32661318/modifying-authcomponent-identify-method/32669470#32669470)

What I'm trying to implement is token based access to API using Basic Auth over SSL.  I have the API prefix setup and working, and I've successfully used Basic authentication AS LONG AS the fields defined for username & password are within the Tokens table, as below:

```
public function initialize() {
    parent::initialize();
    $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
    $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
        'authenticate' => [
            'Basic' => [
                'fields' => ['username' => 'user_id', 'password' => 'app_key_hashed'],
                'userModel' => 'Tokens'
            ]
        ],
        'storage' => 'Memory',
        'unauthorizedRedirect' => false
    ]);
}
```

Ultimately I would like to authenticate using the User's email (From the Users model) AND the app_key (from the Tokens model).  After reading the documentation (and the above linked question and answer), I feel as though I need to implement this using a custom finder.  So I change the code above to read:

```
public function initialize() {
    parent::initialize();
    $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
    $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
        'authenticate' => [
            'Basic' => [
                'fields' => ['username' => 'user.email', 'password' => 'app_key_hashed'],
                'userModel' => 'Tokens',
                'finder' => 'auth'
            ]
        ],
        'storage' => 'Memory',
        'unauthorizedRedirect' => false
    ]);
}
```

And include the following in my TokensTable.php:

```
    /**
 * Custom finder for Auth
 */

public function findAuth(\Cake\ORM\Query $query, array $options) {
    $query->select(['id', 'user_id', 'app_key_hashed', 'Users.email'])
            ->where(['Tokens.inactive' => 0])
            ->contain(['Users']);

    return $query;
}
```

When I do this, the return message is this:

```
{
  "message": "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column    'Tokens.user.email' in 'where clause'",
  "url": "/flight-ops/api/tokens",
  "code": 500
}
```

I feel as though the issue isn't in the custom finder finding the data, but in the filtering of the data by the Auth component.  Am I correct?  Am I missing something simple?  Am I barking up the right tree using a custom finder?

I'm using CakePHP 3.2.4.

Thanks for your help!

Here are my Tables and relationships:

```
class TokensTable extends Table
{

/**
 * Initialize method
 *
 * @param array $config The configuration for the Table.
 * @return void
 */
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->table('tokens');
    $this->displayField('id');
    $this->primaryKey('id');

    $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

    $this->belongsTo('Users', [
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
    ]);
}
}

class UsersTable extends Table
{

/**
 * Initialize method
 *
 * @param array $config The configuration for the Table.
 * @return void
 */
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->table('users');
    $this->displayField('id');
    $this->primaryKey('id');

    $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

    $this->hasOne('Tokens', [
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
    ]);
}
}
```

Comment: We need to see what your table relations look like. It looks as if there is an incorrect value for the where statement.

Comment: Hi chrisShick, I updated to include the table and relationship data. Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: Are you sure that is your findAuth function? According to the error, it looks like you are putting 'Tokens.user.email' in the where clause which would invalid sql.

Comment: It is.  I've done some experimenting trying different notations in both the findAuth function and the Auth component initialization, and have not found a successful combination.  For example, I just changed the component initialization to be "Users.email" for the username, still get the same warning, well...except it says "Tokens.Users.Email".  I believe the issue to be in the query generated by the Auth component itself that is the base $query then further manipulated in the findAuth function.

Comment: I am pretty positive that you can't use dot notation to tell the component what field you are looking for. You may want to take a look at a previous post that I answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33272426/pass-extra-data-to-finder-auth/33445801#33445801

Comment: I think you're right, it was wishful thinking on my part.  I've been looking at _query in BaseAuthenticate and trying to figure out if there's a way to make that work...but I think I'll be extending the BaseAuthenticate class.  Thanks for taking a look at it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, thanks to Chris in the comments above for confirming I was heading in the right direction.  I accomplished the task in the question by extending the BasicAuthenticate class (really, I only extended a function from BaseAuthenticate, but I wanted to include BasicAuthenticate at the same time, so I extended that class).

Here is my TokenBasicAuthenticate class:

```
namespace App\Auth;

use Cake\Auth\BasicAuthenticate;
use Cake\Network\Request;
use Cake\Network\Response;
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;

class TokenBasicAuthenticate extends BasicAuthenticate{

    protected function _query($username)
    {

        $config = $this->_config;
        $table = TableRegistry::get($config['userModel']);

        $query = $table->find()
                        ->where([$config['userModel'] . '.inactive' => 0])
                        ->contain([$config['relatedModel']])
                        ->matching($config['relatedModel'], function($q) use ($config, $username) {
                           return $q->where([$config['fields']['username'] => $username]) ;
                        });

        return $query;

    }
}
```

I also changed my Auth initialization to this:

```
public function initialize() {
        parent::initialize();
        $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
        $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
            'authenticate' => [
                'TokenBasic' => [
                    'fields' => ['username' => 'Users.email', 'password' => 'app_key_hashed'],
                    'userModel' => 'Tokens',
                    'relatedModel' => 'Users',
                    'finder' => 'auth'
                ]
            ],
            'storage' => 'Memory',
            'unauthorizedRedirect' => false
        ]);
    }
```

As you can see, I included an additional field 'relatedModel' to reference the related model.

It works well for my needs, hopefully someone else finds this as useful.  I'm sure there's more than one way to complete this, feel free to add anything useful.